# Append char in SQL select Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL. I have one banking project, in the in one table have values like this.

```
Type    Amount  
-----  -------

Credit   5000    
Debit    2000

Debit    1000........... so on
```

Now i need to Fetch these columns.Using Select Statement i can fetch,  But i need to append '-' for amount which is Debited( like Debit  '-2000'...) and '+' for Credited Amount.

How to append these functions in amount column Using Select Query.
Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use decode instead of case.

To print the signed value as string

```
select decode(type,'Debit','-','+')||amount as value from tab;
```

To keep the value as number but signed

```
select decode(type,'Debit',-1*amount,amount) as value from tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a `CASE` statement checking the Type for Debit and then apply -1 to the amount:

```
SELECT
Type,
CASE WHEN Type='Debit' THEN (Amount*(-1)) ELSE Amount END AS Value
FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1):

To show amount like  -1000 and +2000 for Debit and Credit respecivelly, one should present those amount like 'strings'

```
select
    Type,
    case
        when Type = 'Credit' then '+' + convert(varchar, Amount)
        else '-' + convert(varchar, Amount)
    end as Amount
from
    tab
```